# Restricting max heap size of application running under Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, heap-memory, adoptopenjdk

## Problem

I am trying to restrict max heap size of the application running under Intellij IDEA - in order to detect memory problems as early as possible.

So far I have tried to pass custom JVM option in *Run/Debug Configurations > CLI arguments to your application.*

```
-Xmx128M
```

This resulted in Intellij producing the following command:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk-11-hotspot-amd64/bin/java \
  -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 \
  -classpath /home/username/ws/projectname/target/classes:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/annotations/23.0.0/annotations-23.0.0.jar:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/reflections/reflections/0.9.10/reflections-0.9.10.jar:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.19.0-GA/javassist-3.19.0-GA.jar:/home/username/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/annotations/2.0.1/annotations-2.0.1.jar:/home/username/.m2/repository/com/github/matejtymes/javafixes/1.3.2/javafixes-1.3.2.jar:...:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/bgee/log4jdbc-log4j2/log4jdbc-log4j2-jdbc4.1/1.16/log4jdbc-log4j2-jdbc4.1-1.16.jar com.companyname.rootpackage.MainApplicationClass \
  -Xmx128M
```

Which does not restrict max heap size to 128MB. But this would have:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk-11-hotspot-amd64/bin/java \
  -Xmx128M \
  -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 \
  -classpath /home/username/ws/projectname/target/classes:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/annotations/23.0.0/annotations-23.0.0.jar:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/reflections/reflections/0.9.10/reflections-0.9.10.jar:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.19.0-GA/javassist-3.19.0-GA.jar:/home/username/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/annotations/2.0.1/annotations-2.0.1.jar:/home/username/.m2/repository/com/github/matejtymes/javafixes/1.3.2/javafixes-1.3.2.jar:...:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/bgee/log4jdbc-log4j2/log4jdbc-log4j2-jdbc4.1/1.16/log4jdbc-log4j2-jdbc4.1-1.16.jar com.companyname.rootpackage.MainApplicationClass
```

I have changed paths and project names, and cut-out large portion of the jars added to classpath.

I know that the first command does not restrict maximum heap size because I have seen the output of `Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()` - which returned ~5GB (1/4th of total RAM available on my development machine - that's the default JDK setting).

I know that the second command *does* restrict maximum heap size because I have tried it outside of Intellij. The output of `Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()` had changed accordingly.

## Questions

1. Is it normal for `-Xmx` option to work only it it's defined before the classpath?
2. Is it possible to restrict max heap size of the application in other way than by using `CLI arguments to your application.`?

## Versions used

Java

```
openjdk 11.0.11 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9 (build 11.0.11+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9 (build 11.0.11+9, mixed mode)
```

Intellij IDEA

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.2 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-232.9921.47, built on September 12, 2023
```

OS

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux bookworm/sid"
```

Comment: `-Xmx128M` is a JVM argument, not an argument for your application.

Comment: You added it as command line argument, it is a VM argument.

Comment: I see, thank you for the clarification. I have somehow missed that